# I cant show the API versions in response header with ApiVersioning .net Core

Tags: api, asp.net-core, api-versioning, aspnet-api-versioning

I follow the instruction [REST API versioning with ASP.NET Core](https://dev.to/99darshan/restful-web-api-versioning-with-asp-net-core-1e8g) to show My API version in the response header.

This is my **Configuration code**:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson();
        services.AddMvc(opt =>
        {

        services.AddRouting(env => env.LowercaseUrls = true);
        services.AddApiVersioning(opt => {
            opt.ApiVersionReader = new MediaTypeApiVersionReader();
            opt.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
            opt.ReportApiVersions = true;
            opt.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
            opt.ApiVersionSelector = new CurrentImplementationApiVersionSelector(opt);
        });
    }
```

and this is my **Controller** :

```
[Route("/")]
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
public class RootController:Controller
{
    [HttpGet(Name =nameof(GetRoot))]
    public IActionResult GetRoot()
    {
        var response = new { href = Url.Link(nameof(GetRoot),null) };
        return Ok(response);
    }
}
```

when I test my API with postman I got this result :

[image]

I don't know why `opt.ReportApiVersions = true;` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason *why* it behaves this way is to disambiguate an API controller from a UI controller. In ASP.NET Core, there's not really any other built-in way to do so as - *a controller is a controller*.

There are a few other ways to change this behavior:

- Opt out with `options.UseApiBehavior = false` as the was the case before `[ApiController]`
- Add a custom **IApiControllerSpecification** that identifies an API controller (there's a built-in implementation that understands `[ApiController]`)
- Replace the default **IApiControllerFilter** service, which is really just an aggregation over all registered **IApiControllerSpecification** implementations

I hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. I have to add `[ApiController]` to my Controller:

```
[Route("/")]
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[ApiController]
public class RootController:Controller
{
    [HttpGet(Name =nameof(GetRoot))]
    public IActionResult GetRoot()
    {
        var response = new { href = Url.Link(nameof(GetRoot),null) };
        return Ok(response);
    }
}
```